# istream not consuming characters?

Tags: c++, stream, istream

I have a istringstream called 'is' and contains the string "101a0101". My code here:

```
cout << is.str() << endl;

char bit;
while (is >> bit) {
    if (bit == '0') /* do stuff */;
    else if (bit == '1') /* do stuff */;
    else break;
}

cout << is.str() << endl;
```

Here's my output

```
output:   
101a0101
101a0101
```

Why isn't my istringstream consuming characters?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the output to be? `str()` returns a copy of the *entire* character sequence. It doesn't display what hasn't yet been read.

Comment: I expect the second output (after the loop) to be "a0101" since, my loop will consume all characters up to the 'a'. Doesn't the line `while (is >> bit)` remove one char from the stream and place it in bit? And if not, how can I?

Comment: Does `istream` have a `str` method? Did you mean `istringstream`?

Comment: @NateKohl Yes, I do mean `istringstream`, istream doesn't have a `str()` method.

Comment: @NateKohl `std::istringstream` *is* an `std::istream`.

Comment: @theMonster Yes, `is >> bit` removes one character from the stream, but as I said `str()` returns the entire content of the stream.

Comment: @0x499602D2 ok, how do I print the current contents of the stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing the content of the stream using `str()` will return you then *entire* character sequence in the buffer. If you need to access the unread subsequence of the stream, you can use `substr()` with `tellg()`:

```
std::string unread = is.str().substr(is.tellg());
std::cout << unread; // "a0101"
```

Comment: ...or, if you don't mind consuming characters from the stream: `std::string remainder; is << remainder; std::cout << remainder;`